# Asp.net Custom Control pass object as a property

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Asp.Net custom control i want to pass an object as a property (like we pass width / color) Is there anyway i can do that in design time?

Example:

Custom control is a <asp:Panel> and i would like to pass

**<cus:CustomPanel ID="Panel11" runat="server" CustomObject="student" />**

student object is instantiated in code behind and my custom panel is coded like this

```
public class CustomPanel:Panel
{
    [Browsable(true), Category("Data")]
    public object CustomObject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't just pass the student object to the CustomPanel in code-behind?

Comment: I can pass it but since i'm designing as component looking for a design time support. currently i could not assign it in design time

Comment: Can i do anything with Eval in aspx

Comment: Is this going to be a child element in your custom panel?

Comment: @James Johnson: It is a custom property

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly not set your custom property as string type.
then you could catch the property on init and create the apropriate object with a switch statement:

```
    public class CustomPanel:Panel
    {
      [Browsable(true), Category("Data")]
      public string CustomObject { get; set; }
    }
```

then within pageload or int you can build the correct Object

```
    switch (CustomObject)
        {
            case "Student":
                CustomObject student = new CustomObject();
                break;
            case "Staff":
                CustomObject staff = new CustomObject();
                break;
            default:
                CustomObject student = new CustomObject();
                break;
        }
```